# Region.GetBounds(Graphics) has different values of Width in local and Remote desktop C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, region, drawrectangle

- RectangleF.Width is giving different values in physical login and
  remote desktop login.
- This issue is observed with Windows 10

[image]

[image]

Code snippet used in the sample is below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces))
        {
            string text;
            RectangleF textRectangle;
            Region[] regions;
            using (Graphics graphics = textBox1.CreateGraphics())
            {
                text = textBox1.Text;
                Font font = textBox1.Font;

                textRectangle = new RectangleF(0, 0, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);

                CharacterRange[] characterRanges = { new CharacterRange(0, text.Length) };

                stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(characterRanges);

                regions = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, textRectangle, stringFormat);

                textRectangle = regions[0].GetBounds(graphics);
            }

            foreach (Region region in regions)
            {
                region.Dispose();
            }

            richTextBox1.Clear();

            richTextBox1.AppendText($"Text : {text}" + Environment.NewLine + "RectangleF Properties:"+ Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"RectangleF.X      : {textRectangle.X}" + Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"RectangleF.Y      : {textRectangle.Y}" + Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"RectangleF.Height : {textRectangle.Height}" + Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"RectangleF.Width  : {textRectangle.Width}" + Environment.NewLine);
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"RectangleF.Right  : {textRectangle.Right}" + Environment.NewLine);

        }
    }
```

Fonts are same:

[image]

Comment: It is not the same font, note how the top one is a little fatter.  Different fonts produce text with different sizes.  Multiple reasons, font fallback is a gritty detail.  But starting with Win10, the system is now capable of rendering dpi-virtualized text with a correctly virtualized font that produces sharp outlines.

Comment: Fonts are same.. For the same machine, during remote login I could see different values and in direct login i could see different values. I have added one more entry to show Font details in the post

Comment: What's also peculiar is that [if you measure the text in the screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq1oj.png), the '0' actually sticks out at the bottom, meaning the height should be _14_. So the method is not accurate _anyway_. Maybe you should look deeper into what is actually used by the system to draw in there.